# Array of structures: printing all members of each structure

Tags: c

I'm trying to print out all the members of each structure from a list. I was provided the print functions below to print out an element from a generic list.

Here is the structure definition of my list, which is in a generic list ADT c file:

```
struct list_type {
  void *data;
  int size;
  int capacity;
  int elementSize;
  int (*comparePtr) (void *d1, void *d2);
};
```

So in a generic list ADT c file, I have this print function:

```
// client needs to send a pointer to a function capable of printing an element
void printl(ListType listptr, void (*printItem) (void *d)) {
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i < listptr->size; i++) {
    // since we cannot use data[i], we need to calculate the address
    // of the element to be sent to the client's print function
    // since data is of type void, the formula is:
    // the beginning address of the array + (offset x element size)
    printItem(listptr->data + i * (listptr->elementSize) );
    printf(" ");
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

I call my printl function like so:

```
printl(clientList, printItem);
```

In my driver file, there's a function to print out an element from the list:

```
void printItem (int* p) {
    printf("%d", *p);
    //`my attempt at printing the members of an individual structure from the list
    // printf("%s", ((Client *)&p)[0]); 
}
```

Here is my `Client` structure definition:

```
struct client_tag {
    char id[5];
    char name[30];
    char email[30];
    char phoneNum[15];
};
```

When I run the program, I get a bunch of weird characters. How do I fix this?

Comment: We need to see how `printl` is called and what the structure definition is and what ListType is.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve - How to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example

Comment: @Schwern Okay, I provided those. I hope I gave enough, my code is quite long, so I wasn't sure how much needed to be included.

Comment: @Jamine We'll need to see how `clientList` is defined and initialized. Basically you need to provide a minimal complete example.

Comment: I've pretty sure that `void* + int` is not well defined, i.e. the argument to your `printItem()` call. I think you need to cast `listptr->data` to `(char*)`. I'm surprised that this compiled.

Comment: @MarkLakata My professor said to ignore all the warnings and that it would work, which it does with another example (array of ints). She also said we wouldn't need to change anything from her file (the one with `printl` function). So I'm trying to figure out how to modify my `printItem()`

Comment: `printf("%d",...)` will never print weird characters. It will only print digits (0-9). If you are getting weird characters, then you have not shown us the code that is not working. If you are refering to the part that you commented out, then you need to tell us what `Client` is and why you are using `&p` instead of `p`.  `&p` is almost certainly incorrect, as `p` is  already a pointer, so there is no need to dereference it.

Comment: Never ignore warnings. They are there for a reason.

Comment: @MarkLakata I'll add in my Client structure definition, it's the element of the list and its members contain char arrays, so the int won't work for my case.

Comment: @Jasmine What is "ListType" ? show us what you do with Client in your print function.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you left out the line

```
typedef struct client_tag Client;
```

and assuming the strings of `Client` are guaranteed to be null terminated, this is the idea:

```
void printItem (const Client* p) {
    printf("%s\n", p->id);
}
```

Comment: Your assumptions are correct. The problem though, the `printItem` needs to work for various structures (I have three total) within the same driver class.

Comment: @Jasmine There are no point to use the same function if you use pointer of function !

Comment: @Stargateur I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: @Jasmine - If you refer to the print function with a pointer (a variable that holds the address of the function, in this case) you can simply set the pointer to point to a different function for each of the 3 cases. What this comment neglects to address however, is that if you can identify the structure type to know you need a different function, you can also identify the structure to know that a single function should behave in one way or another. I guess you can just look at the members of the `ListType` struct to deduce which of the 3 structs you're dealing with. :)